# Running SSIS package through SQL server agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with excel connection manager. Thus, I need to run it in 32-bit environment. 
I  configured the SQL-server job to run in 32-bit environment by doing the following:

Job properties-> Execution options-> use 32 bit runtime.

But I am getting this error:

Code: 0xC0209302     Source: Package Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2017-02-16 10:14:22.94     Code: 0xC001002B     Source: Package Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Please suggest a way in which I can run the SSIS package through sql-server job agent. Thanks!

Comment: There are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the ACE (Excel) driver. You don't *need* 32-bit to import Excel files. Have you tried running the package in 64-bit mode?

Comment: Did you try installing the driver that the error message is telling you is missing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I tried running the package in 64 bit verison. It gives me similar error as stated above. The only difference in error is, it says "If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode". The SSIS package works fine in Visual studio but gives error in SQL server.

Comment: That means that you haven't installed *any* driver on the SQL Server machine. You have to install it

Comment: @TabAlleman No I have not downloaded the driver. I found on google that running it under 32-bit environment will solve the problem. But it didn't.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I will install the driver on the server machine. Can you please suggest ideally which drive should i install(32-bit/64bit) and share link if possible from where I can download it.

Comment: it depends on your target server not your local design environment

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

You need to download new data access engine, what I am guessing is you were trying to deploy a package to the server with old data access engine installed such as `jet`

here is the link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

login to the target server, download either 32-bit or 64-bit based on your server version and installed. After that everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a alter way. Open the excel file in Microsoft office Excel, and save it as "Excel 97-2003 Workbook". Then, use the new saved excel file in your file connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have configured to run package in correct architecture.
Navigate in SSDT to Project>>Properties>>Debugging>>Run64 bit Runtime>> Set True/False acc to arch of your machine and check.